# Where is SetPageReserved() defined in Linux Kernel v3.10

Tags: linux-kernel

I found the definition of "SetPageReserved()" in linux v2.6.25 [here](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v2.6.25/source/include/linux/page-flags.h#L224) but I couldn't find it's definition in v3.10. I can call this function/macro from a kernel module and build it with out compilation error. Where is it defined exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have 3.10 at hand but in 4.13 it's still in
`include/linux/page-flags.h`:

```
#define SETPAGEFLAG(uname, lname, policy)               \
static __always_inline void SetPage##uname(struct page *page)       \
    { set_bit(PG_##lname, &policy(page, 1)->flags); }
(...)
#define PAGEFLAG(uname, lname, policy)                  \
    TESTPAGEFLAG(uname, lname, policy)              \
    SETPAGEFLAG(uname, lname, policy)               \
    CLEARPAGEFLAG(uname, lname, policy)
(...)
PAGEFLAG(Reserved, reserved, PF_NO_COMPOUND)
```